# Using char array for title bar and adding variables C++

Tags: c++, variables, visual-studio-2012, window, titlebar

I'm trying to use a char array for a title bar, but I need to make some interactive components. I'm not sure if this is possible, if I'm just doing it wrong, or if there is a better way to do it.

Here's what I have (not exactly, but it has the main point of what I'm trying to get across):

```
char     title[] = "Some text to be in the title bar " + var1 + "," + var2 + ".";
```

I am programming in C++ on Visual Studios. The larger program utilizes OpenGL, gltools.lib and freeglut.lib.

Any advice/suggestions?

Comment: `is a better way to do it?:` Yes use `std::string`.

Comment: `std::string title = "Some text to be in the title bar " + var1 + "," + var2 + ".";`. This assuming that `var1` and `var2` are themselves `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/).

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   stringstream ss;
   int var1 = 100;
   int var2 = 200;
   ss << "Some text to be in the title bar " << var1 << "," << var2 << ".";
   cout << ss.str();
   // if you want c-style char arrays
   // cout << ss.str().c_str();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And this will send that text to the title bar of a window?